# how to start svnserve with systemctl systemd

Tags: svn, systemd

subversion package in debian jessie does not include a systemd service file. what is the simplest solution for automatic start. i try

```
[Unit]
Description=Subversion protocol daemon
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
#EnvironmentFile=/etc/conf.d/svnserve
#ExecStart=/usr/bin/svnserve --daemon $SVNSERVE_ARGS
ExecStart=/usr/bin/svnserve -d -r /svnFolder/repositories
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=svnserve.service
```

it is an adaptation of https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=190127 but i have put the arguments directly for svnserve directly here.

what can be improved?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's off topic for SO as it does not directly relate to programming. The Unix and Linux StackExchange site would be a better fit.

Comment: systemd files are largely the same between all distributions that are based on systemd. Have you looked at equivalent files from Arch Linux, Fedora or Ubuntu for inspiration?

Comment: What is the problem with your current solution? It doesn't work? What error does it produce?

Answer (score 35):

Here is a proposal to setup `svnserve` service "[the-Debian-way](https://wiki.debian.org/SVNAdministrationTutorial)" running with a dedicated `svn` service account with proper logging. According to [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard), repositories should be stored in `/srv/`:

```
mkdir -p /srv/svn/repos; chown svn /srv/svn/repos
```

First, the service configuration for systemd `/etc/systemd/system/svnserve.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Subversion protocol daemon
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
RuntimeDirectory=svnserve
PIDFile=/run/svnserve/svnserve.pid
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/svnserve
ExecStart=/usr/bin/svnserve $DAEMON_ARGS
User=svn
Group=svn
KillMode=control-group
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Second, the service startup options at `/etc/default/svnserve`:

```
# svnserve options
DAEMON_ARGS="--daemon --pid-file /run/svnserve/svnserve.pid --root /srv/svn/repos --log-file /var/log/svnserve/svnserve.log"
```

To work properly, the folder for log files must be created with proper ownership and run location for pid file too:

```
mkdir /var/log/svnserve; chown svn /var/log/svnserve
mkdir -p /run/svnserve; chown svn /run/svnserve
```

To end with log rotation configuration `/etc/logrotate.d/svnserve`:

```
/var/log/svnserve/*.log {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 14
    compress
    notifempty
    create 640 svn adm
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
            if /bin/systemctl status svnserve > /dev/null ; then \
                /bin/systemctl restart svnserve > /dev/null; \
            fi;
    endscript
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Yves Martin Thanks for this solution. I recently used a variation of this solution and had a few comments. First off, in `/etc/default/svnserve`, the arg flag for the log file should be `--log-file`, not `--log`. Also, while creating the log directory only needs to be done once, `/var/run` is not guaranteed to persist. It would be better to use the [`RuntimeDirectory=`](http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/systemd.exec.html#RuntimeDirectory=) directive. In Ubuntu, `/var/run` is a symlink to `/run`.

Comment: @Grexis Many thanks for your improvements. This service setup looks great now. I learned yet another feature of `systemd` and fix my FHS about `/run`. Thank you

Comment: Won't this break outstanding svn connections during the logrotation?  That is, if I'm in the middle of an svn operation, say, a long checkout on an automated builder, won't the "restart" interrupt and thus break my svn connection and thus my build?

Comment: Good question. As far as I know, `svnserve` forks for each request and waits for child to stop before exiting... so I think there is no chance to cancel an in-progress operation

Comment: I reverted `KillMode` to default `control-group` or else child processes are left running. `ExecReload` does not have expected effect, process is simply killed.

Comment: It seems `sudo mkdir -p /srv/svn/repos` is necessay before editing `/etc/default/svnserve` if there is no this dir, `/srv/svn/repos`.

Comment: I'd like to draw attention to an answer below by @Matt Hovey that suggests removing the alias line. I too find that having this line prevents the systemctl enable command from working (on Ubuntu 20.04).

Comment: The combination of `User=...` + `PIDFile=/run/...` wasn't working for me (on RHEL7), because user `svn` can't write to `/run/...`. Even with a `svn` user owned subdirectory, the subdirectory was getting wiped out. I got this to work by ditching the PID file and using `GuessMainPID=true`.

Comment: RHEL cleans /run at boot, whereas Debian does not. It may be interesting to find a portable way to write non-root PID file from systemd service.

Answer (score 2):

***Update:*** My answer below has been obsoleted. These improvements and others have been incorporated into [Yves Martin's excellent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40584047/464087).

I have two improvements: it's generally recommended not to run such things as root. Create a user for this, for example 'svn'. It is also [recommended](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) to explicitly specify a PID file when using forking. My svnserve.service looks much like yours except I add the lines:

```
User=svn
Group=svn
PIDFile=/usr/local/svn/svnserve.pid
ExecStart=/usr/bin/svnserve  -d -r /usr/local/svn/repos --pid-file /usr/local/svn/svnserve.pid
```

Comment: A PID FILE is looks like a good idea  as does the separate user.  thank you!

Comment: I've changed this to put the pid file in a directory fully managed by the svn user rather than /var/run/svnserve. /var/run was temporary on the system I was using. Perhaps it would be better to have a startup script create and permission /var/run/svnserve but I chose not to deal with it. Perhaps someone else can improve this.

Comment: @EricS I had the same issue. The [`RuntimeDirectory=`](http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/systemd.exec.html#RuntimeDirectory=) directive is perfect for this, and there is [`tmpfiles.d`](http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/tmpfiles.d.html) for anything more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

One comment on Yves Martin's excellent answer above (I don't have the rep points to comment yet):

When trying to enable the service to start on boot, I'd get an error:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable svnserve.service
Failed to execute operation: Invalid argument
```

After doing some research I found you apparently cannot set an alias to the same name as the service. Deleting the Alias line from the [Install] section of the svnserve.service solved the issue:

```
[Unit]
Description=Subversion protocol daemon
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
RuntimeDirectory=svnserve
PIDFile=/run/svnserve/svnserve.pid
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/svnserve
ExecStart=/usr/bin/svnserve $DAEMON_ARGS
User=svn
Group=svn
KillMode=control-group
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I find this to be true also, on Ubuntu 20.04. I get a different error from enable though: "Failed to enable unit: File /etc/systemd/system/svnserve.service already exists." Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

(I'd make this a comment on [@Yves Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40584047/464087), but this is a new account and I'm not allowed to comment. :-P )

With SELinux, this solution doesn't allow for an autostart of the daemon.  I made a few changes to make it happy.  The svnserve daemon does not have *open* rights in the /var/log tree.  Placing the log in the svn account's domain resolves a security whine.

In /etc/systemd/system/svnserve.service:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/svnserve --daemon \
  --pid-file /var/run/svnserve/svnserve.pid \
  --root /project/svn/repos \
  --log-file /project/svn/log/svnserve.log
```

In /etc/logrotate.d/svnserve:

```
/project/svn/log/*.log {  # path changed
...
  create 644 svn svn   # corrected group and made world-readable
...
```

Finally, make the svn repos and log directory have the correct ownership and security type:

```
sudo mkdir /project/svn
sudo chmod 755 /project/svn
sudo mkdir /project/svn/repos /project/svn/log
sudo chown -R svn:svn /project/svn
sudo semanage fcontext --add --type svnserve_content_t "/project/svn(/.*)?"
sudo restorecon -Rv /project/svn
```

(Obviously, change /project/svn to wherever you have decided to put your repo structure.  /var/svn is common and the rules already exist for that directory tree, making the last couple lines above unnecessary.)

Comment: semanage add option requires two '-', as in: # sudo semanage fcontext --add --type svnserve_content_t "/project/svn(/.*)?"

Comment: Thanks @Mac.  Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this replacement of xinet -> systemd:
(This was mostly gleaned from http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/inetd.html

You would need to create two files:

svnserve.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=SVN Socket for Per-Connection Servers

[Socket]
ListenStream=3690
Accept=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

and 
svnserve@.service

```
[Unit]
Description=SVN Per-Connection Server

[Service]
User=svn
Group=svn
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/svnserve -i -r /srv/repositories/svn/repositories
StandardInput=socket
```

Copy both files to /etc/systemd/system/

then

```
systemctl enable svnserve.socket
systemctl start svnserve.socket
systemctl status svnserve.socket
```